# java virtual machine specification

Tags: jvm

I'm reading "java virtual machine specification edition 7",there is something really puzzle me,here is the question:

The current frame (§2.6) is used in this case to restore the state of the invoker, including its local variables and operand stack, with the program counter of the invoker appropriately incremented **to skip past the method invocation instruction**. Execution then continues normally in the invoking method's frame with the returned value (if any) pushed onto the operand stack of that frame.

so what does " **skip past the method invocation instruction**"  mean?Can anybody explain it?Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

After a method is done it has to return to the invoker. The location to continue program execution is *past the method invoking instruction* in the code of the invoking method.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that the program is executing function_A which calls a function_B. Before calling the function_B, state of local variables of function_A has to be saved, pushed to the stack. Here we save the program counter past the invocation of function_B so we could know where to continue after the function_B returned from the execution. Then, parameters of the function_B are pushed to the stack and the function_B is invoked. When the function_B returns from execution, local variables of function_A are restored from the stack and the program counter which points to the next instruction right after the invocation of function_B.